# How to search a partial text in dict?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, dictionary

I have a dictionary and would like to be able to search with a partial variable and return a text.

```
df = pd.read_csv('MY_PATH')
d = defaultdict(lambda: 'Error, input not listed')
d.update(df.set_index('msg')['reply'].to_dict())
d[last_msg()]
```

`last_msg()` should be my partial variable, and `d` is my dictionary.

The index on my dictionary is column `msg` from `df`.

In column `msg` i have a sample like `Jeff Bezos`.

In column `reply` i have a matching reply `Jeff Bezos is the CEO of Amazon`

**How can I search a partial value in column `msg` and return matching value from column `reply`?**

I want to search just `Jeff` or just `Bezos` and get the matching reply `Jeff Bezos is the CEO of Amazon`

PS. Alternatives to `defaultdict` may also help improve the code.

EDIT: `last_msg()` code extracts a text from selenium element.

```
def last_msg():
try:
    post = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("_12pGw")
    ultimo = len(post) - 1
    texto = post[ultimo].find_element_by_css_selector(
        "span.selectable-text").text
    return texto
except Exception as e:
    print("Error, input not valid")
```

When I print(d):

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x0000021F959D37B8>, {'Jeff Bezos': 'Jeff Bezos is the CEO of Amazon', 'Serguey Brin': 'Serguey Brin co-founded Google', nan: nan})
```

When I print(df)

```
   Unnamed: 0           msg                            reply
0           0    Jeff Bezos  Jeff Bezos is the CEO of Amazon
1           1  Serguey Brin   Serguey Brin co-founded Google
2           2           NaN                              NaN
3           3           NaN                              NaN
```

Comment: What have you tried for last_msg()?

Comment: @stackErr I added last_msg() code and the printed d and df as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way arround my own question using:

```
d = df.set_index('msg')['reply'].to_dict()
...
        try:
        x = next(v for k, v in d.items() if last_msg() in k)
    except StopIteration:
        x = 'Error, input not listed'
```